# Twitter tweet button with page title and page url

Tags: twitter

I am currently creating a Tweet button for my website but have little knowledge of Twitter. I would like the text to say something similar to 'I like' and be followed by the title and url for the current page. I can make it display the text that I would like, or the page title, but cannot seem to get the text AND the page title into the tweet together.

So I would like the tweet to be... 'I like [page title] at Phil's website - [url for specific page]'

Is it possible to get it from meta data and open-graph similar to how facebook works?

Thanks in advance for any help, the code below is taken from the Twitter website with a few edits made.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Check this out" data-count="horizontal" data-via="DummyUsername">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check this link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Comment: You can use javascript to build the text and then affect it to the button!!! that if you are good at handling string!!!